# I cannot format an int that I have created from a parse method.

Tags: string, formatting, int, format, parseint

In my program I have created an int from a string by using the Integer.parseInt() 
method and now I am at the point where I have to print somethings after it has been used in a calculation but I am getting an error. It prints right up until the point where the ints would be featured.

Any help is appreciated!

This is the error I am getting if it is useful.
The bold part is how far the program prints before it runs into an error.

**You have won: $**Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != java.lang.Integer
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:4302)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printFloat(Formatter.java:2806)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2753)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2520)
    at java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:970)
    at java.io.PrintStream.printf(PrintStream.java:871)
    at SlotMachine.main(SlotMachine.java:50)

```
 //variables declared
    //BALANCE is declared as a constant
            String userBet, dollar, coins;
            int decimal, winnings, dollarToInt, coinsToInt, bet;
            int slot1, slot2, slot3;

    //changing users inputted string to int
            do {
                System.out.print("Enter your bet (or 0 to quit): $");
                userBet = kbd.nextLine();
                decimal = userBet.indexOf(".");
                dollar = userBet.substring(0, (decimal));
                coins = userBet.substring(decimal+1);
                dollarToInt = Integer.parseInt(dollar);
                coinsToInt = Integer.parseInt(coins);
                bet = (dollarToInt*100) + (coinsToInt);

//calculating winnings and new balance
            if (slot1 == slot2) {
                winnings = (slot1 * bet/2);
                System.out.printf("You have won: $%.2f\n", (winnings));
                System.out.printf("Balance: $%.2f\n\n", (winnings - bet + BALANCE));


                if (slot1 == slot3) {
                    winnings = (slot1 * bet/2);
                    System.out.printf("You have won: $%.2f\n", (winnings));
                    System.out.printf("Balance: $%.2f\n\n", (winnings - bet + BALANCE));

                }

                if (slot2 == slot3) {
                    winnings = (slot2 * bet/2);
                    System.out.printf("You have won: $%.2f\n", (winnings));
                    System.out.printf("Balance: $%.2f\n\n", (winnings - bet + BALANCE));
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are formatting an int (winnings) as a Float (%.2f).  Either change Winnings to a Float, or format it as an int.

Comment: because doing that it gives and error even earlier, and doesnt even print the "You have won: $"

Comment: Try changing `System.out.printf("You have won: $%.2f\n", (winnings));` to `System.out.printf("You have won: $%.2f\n", (float) (winnings / 100));`

Comment: this helps but now i have a bunch of logic errors...what if i could not use floats or doubles?

Comment: You've got `dollars` and `coins` as ints.  Why not something like this `System.out.printf("You have won: $%d.%d\n", dollars, coins);`.  You will need to research how to change the second %d to prepend 0s - I cant recall the syntax, but it shouldn't be hard to find